# Is there a way to have a fallback image rather than displaying the first frame of an animated GIF?

Tags: css, email, html-email, animated-gif

I understand that for non compatiable email clients, only the first frame on the animated GIF displays. However, is there a way to have a different fallback image instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the gif in a div with a background image, or just make the first frame of the gif your fallback image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Outlook is the only client that doesn't support them. Try this:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
ANIMATED GIF
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
FALLBACK IMAGE FOR OUTLOOK
<![endif]-->
```

EDIT! Fix for outlook.com eating things inside conditional comments

```
<style type="text/css">
.ecxoutlookcom {
    display:block !important;
}
</style>

<img class="outlookcom" src="http://somewhere.com/something.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="something" style="display:none;" border="0" />
```

Outlook.com adds ecx in front of all your classes before displaying your html, so we can take advantage of that and show a hidden image.

Comment: This dos not work in outlook.com, it just shows and empty cell :-(